Attribute Error while importing ydata_profiling
As I tried to use the pandas profiling or known as ydata-profiling. I started it by  importing the library with the command from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport it throws an AttributeError which says module 'numba' has no attribute 'generated_jit' can this issue be resolved?
I had read the documentaion and try the solutions by setting the numba and pandas-profiling modules to specific versions and the issued isn't resolved. I am expecting a solution which may help me resolving the issue i encountered.

install numba older than 0.59 as generated_jit was removed then

As i am using it in jupyter notebook it couldn't supported installation of older versions of numba once again it throws an error while installing numba older than 0.59.0 as it says it can't meet the requirements .It needs the python version above v3.7

neither using a Jupyter notebook or python>3.7 should stop you installing numba version 0.58.0 which has generated_jit. It will be some other module you have installed in the environment that is either requiring a newer version of numba or numpy
